# Java DAX client dependency throws "com.amazonaws:aws-java-sdk-dynamodb:pom:1.11 was not found" error

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb-dax

I am trying to implement a POC on DAX with DynamoDB. What is the correct DAX java client dependency I need to use ?
Examples refer to

```
    <dependency>
                    <groupId>com.amazonaws</groupId>
                    <artifactId>amazon-dax-client</artifactId>
                    <version>1.0.230341.0</version>
                </dependency>
```

But this dependency throws the following error :
com.amazonaws:aws-java-sdk-dynamodb:pom:1.11 was not found in maven repository during a previous attempt. This failure was cached in the local repository and resolution is not reattempted until the update interval of central has elapsed or updates are forced

Comment: WHy are you using the AWS SDK for Java V1 API that is marked deprecated in AWS Github: https://github.com/awsdocs/aws-doc-sdk-examples.  Using a deprecated API can result in issues like this.